# Validate the URL (if user use http:// https:// www)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate URL and i need a function. So user can type HTTP://, HTTPS://, WWW or just facebook.com. I need to make sure that  everything works regardless of how they type it.

some think like :

```
function ValidateUrl(url){

return CorrectUrl;
}
```

Thank's in advance :)

Comment: dont quite get what you want?

Comment: @Alex if user fill `facebook.com` function should return `https://www.facebook.com/`.

Comment: So.... what you're saying is if the user doesn't specify the http/https or www, you still want things that look like URLs to be recognised as URLs? Is that right? So.... what happens if someone is talking about VB.Net? That's a programming language. There's a very good chance that they don't mean it to be a web address. But how is your system going to know that? How can you tell which ones are actually meant to be URLs and which ones are just strings that happen to contain a dot in the middle?

Comment: @Furqan: note that Stack Overflow isn't a service for writing your code for you. Could you clarify what you're asking?

Comment: Also, did you look for identical questions here on SO before posting? There are numerous similar posts already (several of which are listed on the panel to the right). Did you try any of the answers there? Have you got *any* code to show us so we can see what you've done already?

Comment: You can't slap `www.` on the front of arbitrary domain names. `http://www.example.com` and `http://example.com` may be different sites, or one may not exist at all.

Comment: @Spudley user will only supply social networking sites url like `https://www.facebook.com/pagename`. if user fill url without HTTPS, or WWW i just need to correct it and save it to database.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite yes i know. but i am week in regular expressions.

Comment: @Furqan: sure, but you don't need to know regular expressions to describe what you're trying to achieve in more detail. At the moment, it sounds like you don't know exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: okay, so does that mean there's a limited set of sites you're expecting? (if so, you should mention that in the question). And does it mean that the user is entering *just* a URL, or is it part of a bigger string? Is the field they're entering marked as a URL field? The question gives very little context to what you're trying to do. And again, you need to show us a bit more about what you've already tried; you need to explain the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Try following function

```
function validateURL(textval) {
  var urlregex = new RegExp(
        "^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)");
  return urlregex.test(textval);
}
```

Comment: according to my question `www.facebook.com/pagename` , `http://www.facebook.com/pagename`,
both urls are not correct. correct url is `https://www.facebook.com/pagename`

so if user enter wrong url function should return correct url by adding https, or www etc ..

Answer (score -2):

As per your requirements:

> if user fill facebook.com function should return https://www.facebook.com/

Done:

```
function ValidateUrl(url){
    var CorrectUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/';

    return CorrectUrl;
}
```

Comment: brilliant ;) Can't imagine why TS didn't think of this himself ;P

Comment: -1 doesn't correct the incorrect assumption that all sites need www. and it's not helpful to provide flippant answers.

Comment: :) @Paul D. Waite i think you did not understand my question.

Comment: @Furqan: I think you didn't make your question detailed enough. That's kind of my point with this answer.

Comment: @AD7six: I'm with you on flippancy, but my answer implicitly rejects the idea that the OP asked about a function that works with all websites.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite yes it looks like my question is not clear.